# Is Russia interfering in Catalonian process?

Tags: international-relations, russian-federation, international-law, spain, catalonia

I heard some months ago that not only did the US congress warn about Russia's interference on Catalonian non-official referendum, but that Russians wanted to use Catalonia as a port for their enterprises on Europe.
I must say I am from Spain and I see the process almost dead. What I heard about Russians is they are not bad tourists: they learn the language quickly and they do not cause troubles on street. But as my holidays region I wonder if that malicious suspicion is grounded.

Comment: Not very clear about the question here.  What is the source of "what I heard some months ago".   What is the source of "Russians are not bad tourists" and what is the relevance of that?

Comment: @James K. I do not find the session where that was told on US Congress, not only for a referendum interference, but for the russian interest on using Catalonia as a port for their entreprises at Europe. Anyhow I doubt this is true because russians are not stupids and they should know our king Felipe VI is a hard one. About russian tourist, this spanish gov page says they are the second with more economical expenditure. Also I do not find again a comment saying at Salou (Catalonia) most of people is more happy with them than with english. https://www.rusalia.com/turistas-rusos/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Russian state media consistently supported the right of Catalonia to secede from Spain. It supported a "Yes" vote. ([source](https://www.voanews.com/a/analysts-russia-may-be-helping-catalonia-secessionists/4050196.html))

This is consistent with the Russian position that Crimea should have the right to secede from Ukraine. It is also consistent with a general Russian policy of supporting disruptive movements: Brexit and Trump for example.

There is little evidence of actual interference in the process of the referendum, or evidence of illegal actions by Russian agents.

Comment: There's usually some realpolitik involved in which independence movements a government supports. Is there a reason, besides bolstering Crimea's case, that Russia would support this movement in particular? I don't think the government is a big fan of Chechnyan separatism or the various other independence movements within Russia, just to begin with.

Comment: @Obie2.0 The realpolitik reasons seems to be exploiting contradictions in western powers - it's position about Kosovo independence, for example - and supporting everything that looks to a) weaken the EU and b) distract EU members from looking eastwards.